# Autolayout collapsing space when removing intermediate views

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, autolayout

I am a bit stumped as to how to properly define constraints that will collapse the space between views when a given view is removed. I have tried adding vertical constraints with a greater than or equal relation, however, it seems that the min distance to satisfy the constraint is not preferred.

For example, given the following layout with three constraints V:[A]-5-[B], V:[B]-5-[C], and V:[A]-(>=5)-[C]:

```
[ View A ]
    |
   5 pt
    |
[ View B ]
    |
   5 pt
    |
[ View C ]
```

After removing view B I want it to look like this:

```
[ View A ]
    |
   5 pt
    |
[ View C ]
```

But it looks like this:

```
[ View A ]
    |
   5 pt + 5 pt + height of view B
    |
[ View C ]
```

Comment: +1 for a clear and neatly formatted question

Comment: Do you remove the view B or just hide it? do you need it to be restored at some point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for this to be scalable, you're probably going to have to do it in code.  I use something like

```
UIView *superView = /* whatever the superview of your views is, probably self.view in a lot of cases */
NSArray *arrViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:/* put only the things you want to show in here, do not put the hidden things, and put them in order from top to bottom */, nil];
CGFloat buffer = 5;

[superView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:[arrViews objectAtIndex:0] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:buffer]];
for (int i = 1; i < arrViews.count; i++)
{
     [superView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:[arrViews objectAtIndex:i] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:[arrViews objectAtIndex:i-1] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:buffer]];
}
[superView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:[arrViews lastObject] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:-1*(buffer)]];
```

This will put a fixed spacing (of size = `buffer`) between the top item and it's superview, then between each subview and the subview directly above it, then between the bottom view and the superview.  You'll have to call this every time you remove an item from `arrViews`, then call `[superView needsLayout]`.  You also need to make sure height constraints are set somehow, or you'll get errors.  If everything is going to be the same height, you could just add another line in the loop to add a height constraint as well.

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this with a UIStackView?

Answer (score 9):

You could add V:[A]-5-[C] with a lover priority, below 1000.

```
[superview]
    |
[ View A ]
    |             |
   5 pt (1000)    | 
    |             |
[ View B ]       5 pt (999)
    |             |
   5 pt (1000)    |
    |             |
[ View C ]
```

Comment: This approach will spam the "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." warnings. The other downside is that it does not scale well the more views you add vertically.

Comment: @JackRowlingson Just built a test project with this approach - no warnings. Looks like you have some other conflicting constraints. Guess you've snapped View C to the bottom somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to programmatically rewire the constraints so that `View C`'s constraint to `View B` points to `View A` instead, and make sure the constraint from `View A` to `View B` is  removed. 
After you do this then call `layoutIfNeeded` on the super view containing these views.