# Autolayout: Fallback constraints for neighbouring views when removing a view

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to make this work in a UICollectionReusableView (UICollectionView Header) context.

[image: AutoLayoutExample]

The height required for strings in UILabels *A*, *B*, and *C* is calculated and set as the gray view's height somewhat like this:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    ....
    CGFloat expectedHeightForLabelB = 0;
    if (stringB.length > 0)
    {
        expectedHeightForLabelB = 8 + calculatedRequiredHeightForStringB;
    }
    ....
    CGFloat expectedHeaderHeight = expectedHeightForLabelA + expectedHeightForLabelB + expectedHeightForLabelC + 8
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width, expectedHeaderHeight);
}
```

In 
`collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:`, I have a condition whereby

```
if (stringB.length == 0)
    [headerView.labelB removeFromSuperView];
```

In this case, I have settled the estimated dynamic height of the gray superview. What I would like then is for UILabels *A* and *C* to have a fallback vertical constraint of 8 pts.

I can only think of 2 possible (not sure if right or wrong) ways to achieve this.

- Programatically applying the new fallback layout in code at 
  `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:`.
- Setting a constraint with constant 8 and and lower priority in storyboard.

What would be the right or best way to achieve this? I have seen an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22388305/2853872) but I would like to gather stronger inputs if there are any.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a IBOutlet of height constraint of B and vertical space between A and B and change it to 0 instead of removing the view

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Hi, I made a mistake in the example picture as there should not be any height constraints on the labels as their heights are supposed to be dynamic. But I get your idea and will try manipulating the label's height itself instead. Will update here after I tried this solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan if the heights are dynamic then if there is no text in label the height will by default become zero.